# Cannot resolve symbol FacebookSdk

Tags: android, facebook

After upgrading my target & compile SDK version to 27, getting "Cannot resolve symbol FacebookSdk". I'm using `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0`.
Tried by Restarting, Invalidating android studio & Gralde sync. Is there any other way to make it work or do I need to update facebook-sdk version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot resolve symbol FacebookSdk

You should use

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0' //4.35.0
```

Then **`File-> Sync Project with Gradle Files`** & **`Clean->Rebuild Project`**

Add this to ***Module-level*** **`/app/build.gradle`** before dependencies:

```
 repositories {
  // You can also use jcenter if you prefer
  mavenCentral() //jcenter()
}
```

Visit [**`Facebook SDK for Android`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply you could use the specific library from FacebookSDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have active internet connection. If yes then sync your project. Its simply done. or use this dependecy

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

Comment: Great that you are trying to answer but I don't think internet is the problem with OP